# Microsoft Word Software for teachers

Tags: microsoft-word

I am working with Microsoft word making a vocabulary list with definitions. Is there any way to take that list and easily convert it into a quiz for free? When I say quiz I mean multiple choice, matching, and fill in the blank questions. I need to print this out in order to give to a class. Ideally, I would want to upload a word document that has a table with one column of words and another of definitions. I would want the program to be able to randomize a quiz based off of it.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc. If you're looking for software, please consult [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Comment: @izzy "``Is there any such add-in or some other program that will help me?`" seems to make it on topic; although it needs ***a lot*** more detail.  Burt, maybe https://sourceforge.net/projects/rquizsem/ or https://sourceforge.net/projects/quizdrill.berlios/? In fact searching for `free vocabulry quiz maker` seems to give soem possibles

Comment: Agreed. Though I doubt there's any program/addon making that with MS Word (do people really use that stuff?) I was hoping for Burt to give some more details on his requirements. For example, how that "quiz" shall work with multiple-choice etc. Cards to turn-around for answers? With graphics, or just text? To print out, or just to run on the computer? On what OS? How much can the software cost if it comes to paid solutions? It's not really clear what exactly Burt is looking for.